# I want to find value less than 100 in a column, but the name of column has a space. How can I edit it?

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

The name of this column is 'observation percentage' as is shown in picture

Comment: it's better to put column name inside quote: `dfDaily[dfDaily['Obeservation Percent'] < 100]`

Comment: how do I get total number of values which are less than 100. I add count() but it gives me number of every column

Comment: Total number: `dfDaily['Obeservation Percent'].le(100).sum()`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`dfObservation = dfDaily[dfDaily['Observation Percent']<100]`